# Android setText() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am developing an App. It has a Prefrences Page and a Main Page.
Now I want to get the Prerfrences and display it in a TextView.
I use setText() for it and it is functioning on Android 4.4.4 but it doesn't work on Android 5.02 :/

Here is My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String patientenname = settings.getString("Patientenname", "bitte eintragen");
    TextView patientennamen  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.patientennamen);
    patientennamen.setText("Name: " + patientenname);
}
```

It would be cool if somebody could help me :)
Philipp

Comment: is it crashing? logs?

Comment: It is not Crashing. It just doesn't show text

Comment: could you post your xml?

Comment: Is it a full text of Activity? What do you recieve for 'getText()'?

Comment: TextView patientennamen = patientennamen.setText("Name: " + patientenname); it has to be like this, but I am not sure because I couldn't solve your doings.

Comment: where is xml-file of your activity placed? What will you receive if you create  layout fully programmatically?

Comment: @Bay - `TextView.setText()` returns void, so that won't work

Comment: If it works on 4.4.4 but doesn't work on 5.0.2 (I'm assuming because 5.02 doesn't exist) it's an API issue. The only thing I see in this code that might cause issues is SharedPreferences or PreferenceManager. Add logs to make sure these are behaving as expected.